# Ubuntu server not getting DNS from DHCP Server?

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

My Ubuntu server doesn't seem to be getting it's DNS settings from the DHCP service on my router.

```
root@dios:/etc/netplan# cat 01-netcfg.yaml
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        enp3s0:
          dhcp4: true
```

It's getting it's IP address from the DHCP server, but the DNS settings seem to be being left out.

```
root@dios:/run/systemd/network# nslookup www.google.com

root@dios:/run/systemd/network# nslookup www.google.com 192.168.2.1
    Server:         192.168.2.1
    Address:        192.168.2.1#53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   www.google.com
    Address: 142.250.80.68
    Name:   www.google.com
    Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:80c::2004
```

My windows PC is working fine, which leads me to believe there's an issue with my Ubuntu server.

I've tried manually setting the DNS server settings in my netplan file:

```
   network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
     ethernets:
       enp3s0:
         dhcp4: true
         dhcp4-overrides:
           use-dns: false
         nameservers:
           addresses: [192.168.2.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

But that doesn't help either.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is in your `/etc/resolv.conf`, are you using systemd-resolved, is the service running `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service`

Comment: Are you sure the DHCP server is sending the DNS server's address? you can use `tcpdump` (`man tcpdump`) or `wireshark` https://www.wireshark.org/ to find out.

Comment: have you tried to add 
```
nameserver 192.168.2.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```
to your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: you can also use `resolvectl status` to check the status of DNS

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Systemd-Resolved service was disabled. I have no idea why or how, but it was. I've enabled it, and everything works smoothly.